# Conver to XLSM then import module - error 91

Tags: excel, vba, automation

Why am I getting object not set error? Seems to be on this line with debug?

```
xlsmTarget.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\CreateUniqueContainers.bas"
```

> However target seems to be set, what have I done wrong?

```
    Sub ConvertXLSFilesToXLSM()
Dim Path As String
Dim DestPath As String
Dim xlsmTarget As Workbook
Const ModulePath As String = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\CreateUniqueContainers.bas"

Path = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\Files\"
DestPath = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\Files\"
WorkFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls")

Do While WorkFile <> ""
    If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & "\" & WorkFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        DestPath & WorkFile & ".xlsm", 
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        xlsmTarget.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ModulePath
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
     End If
     WorkFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You state that "*target seems to be set*", but I don't see any statement that assigns anything to the variable `xlsmTarget`?! As your code doesn't compile: Have you omitted parts of your code?

Comment: Hi @FunThomas, so what needs to be added a `Set xlsmTarget = ActiveWorkbook`? Tried this and get runtime error 1004 Programmatic access to Visual basic Project is not trusted?

Comment: @FunThomas I have added this and also changed Excel settings to allow VBA and script runs without error, but does not import the macro at all?

Comment: https://support.pcmiler.com/en/support/solutions/articles/19000047036-what-does-error-1004-programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted-mean-

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertXLSFilesToXLSM()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\"
    Const MODNAME = "CreateUniqueContainers.bas"
    
    Dim SrcPath As String, DestPath As String
    Dim SrcFile As String, DestFile As String
    Dim n As Long
    
    SrcPath = FOLDER & "Files\"
    DestPath = FOLDER & "Files\"
    SrcFile = Dir(SrcPath & "*.xls*")
    
    Do While SrcFile <> ""
        If Right(SrcFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then
        
            Debug.Print SrcFile
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=SrcPath & "\" & SrcFile
            
            ' replace .xls or .xlsx with .xlsm
            DestFile = DestPath & Split(SrcFile, ".")(0) & ".xlsm"
                 
            ' save with new name
            With ActiveWorkbook
                .SaveAs Filename:=DestFile, _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
                CreateBackup:=False
                
                ' import module and save
               .VBProject.VBComponents.Import FOLDER & MODNAME
               .Save
               .Close
            End With
            n = n + 1
        End If
         
        SrcFile = Dir()
    Loop
    MsgBox n & " files created", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set your variable, and use it.  Also, don't rely on Active*

```
Sub ConvertXLSFilesToXLSM()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim DestPath As String
    Dim xlsmTarget As Workbook

    Const ModulePath As String = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\CreateUniqueContainers.bas"
    Path = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\Files\"
    DestPath = "C:\New Name Test\Testv3\Files\"
    WorkFile = Dir(Path & "*.xls") 

    Do While WorkFile <> ""
        If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then
            Set xlsmTarget = Workbooks.Open(Path & WorkFile)
            xlsmTarget.SaveAs _
              Filename:=DestPath & replace(WorkFile, ".xls", ".xlsm"), _           
              FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, _
              CreateBackup:=False

 
            xlsmTarget.VBProject.VBComponents.Import ModulePath
            'xlsmTarget.Save
            xlsmTarget.Close, True
         End If
         WorkFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This does nothing? Doesn't run?

Comment: @fane I posted this from a phone, so may have some typos.  If you see any, please fix them

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to convert all the files then write another Macro to loop through those files (xlsm) and run a macro? could this be cleaner?

Comment: @scott spotted some more typos in your code (myPath vs Path)

Comment: @scott add Option Explicit to the top of your module.  That'll help with these variable name typo's

Comment: @Scott Manning Please, try the updated code. Refresh the page (this one) before copying it... But please, clarify the next issue: Do you really want iterate between **xls** type workbooks?

Comment: @Scott Manning I am asking about the **xls** issue, because if so, `If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then` code line is useless. Or you want returning all workbooks? I mean `Dir(Path & "*.xls*") ` will return also xlsx, xlsm, xlsa, xlst workbooks...

Comment: @FaneDuru - Updated code doesn't, work, it replaces the name but makes the file unusable and asks me to save the workbook manually which I want this to be automated. Then when trying to open the file does not allow excel to open it. Infact, it does, but again I have to manually set it & trust the source each time I open the document...

Comment: @Scott Manning How exactly does it ask? What message do you see? Then, if (manually) you save it, does it have the necessary module imported? If it asks about trusting source, you should add `DestPath` to Excel Trusted locations... You did not say anything about the **xls** issue...

Comment: @FaneDuru - it needs to run only against XLSM hence converting them. I get the error when opening 'The FIle format and extension of 'filename.xlsm' dont match. Once you select open anyway you are prompted to enable Macro. This is the first of 2 stages as now I need a way to do a loopthrough files and run the macro for each file created.

Comment: @Scott Manning I cannot get you, sorry. You did not answer my clarification questions. 1. "asks me to save the workbook manually" - **How exactly does it ask?**, 2. **does it have the necessary module imported?**, 3. **You did not say anything about the `xls` issue**, 4. adding the path to Excel Trusted Locations (that's why it asks to enable macros) etc.